# Android xml and Java: Get text from Edit Text, cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to getText() from an EditText element for my android application. This is the Java I code I use to declare the edit text:

```
public class LogFragment extends Fragment {

    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View logView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_form, container, false);
        final EditText raceName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
        // Handle buttons here...
        View logButton = logView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogRace);
        logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(R.string.logged_text);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                // develop georeferencing, shared preferences saving, automatic calculations and a results window

                            }
                        });
                mDialog = builder.show();
            }
        });
        return logView;
}
```

This is the EditText built using xml:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/racename"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textSize="8pt">
</EditText>
```

Why am I getting this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    final EditText raceName = (EditText) logView .findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an even less vague of code

```
final EditText race name = (EditText) logView .findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
```

Also cast button

```
 Button buttonedup= (Button) logView .findViewById(R.id.b1);
```